# Finding max and min dates using Moment().max and min not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I have an array of dates and wanted to find the max and min dates in an array.

This is my code:

```js
let date_list = [
"2021-03-19T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-03-20T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-04-12T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-04-13T00:00:00Z",
"2021-04-11T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-04-12T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-03-18T00:00:00Z"
];

let uniq_dates = [...new Set(date_list.map(d => moment.utc(d).format()  ))];
console.log(uniq_dates);

console.log(moment().max(date_list));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I sometimes get an error that says `NaN` or I am getting `Deprecation warning: moment().max is deprecated, use moment.min instead.`

How do I get max and min in an array of dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code.

```js
let date_list = [
"2021-03-19T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-03-20T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-04-12T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-04-13T00:00:00Z",
"2021-04-11T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-04-12T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-03-18T00:00:00Z"
];

let moments = date_list.map(d => moment(d)),
maxDate = moment.max(moments)

console.log(maxDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#reduce` in conjunction with `moment.max`.

```js
let date_list = [
"2021-03-19T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-03-20T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-04-12T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-04-13T00:00:00Z",
"2021-04-11T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-04-12T00:00:00Z", 
"2021-03-18T00:00:00Z"
];

let uniq_dates = [...new Set(date_list.map(d => moment.utc(d).format()  ))];
console.log(uniq_dates);

console.log(uniq_dates.reduce((acc,curr)=>acc.max(curr), moment()));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```